# Why does a WHERE (column) NOT (value) ignore where (column) is NULL?

Tags: mysql

We have a column (lets call it `status`) that can be `NULL`, `processing`, or `closed`.

```
ID    | STATUS
------------------
1     | NULL
2     | NULL
3     | processing
4     | closed
```

We built this scope to find unclosed orders, and it looks like `WHERE 'status' IS NOT 'closed'`. However, this returns:

```
ID    | STATUS
------------------
3     | processing
```

This confused us, as we expected it would return:

```
ID    | STATUS
------------------
1     | NULL
2     | NULL
3     | processing
```

We got around this by doing a compound `WHERE 'status' IS NULL OR 'status' != 'closed'`.

Simple enough, but it's still confusing us as that does not seem intuitive.

I tried looking through the MySQL docs to explain this, and googled a bit, but I couldn't sift through the questions/docs that were just talking about how to look for where is not null; I couldn't find an explanation for why `IS NOT x` would ignore `NULL`.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Is this a MySQL specific thing, is this how most SQL dbs behave?

Comment: Because NULL is an actual value...it has no pure definition...So when you say IS NOT 'closed' It should in fact return the nulls as they are not "closed".  I would expect it to do so.

Comment: Right -- which would make me think that as an actual value, it would be returned in a scope that was looking for `WHERE NOT someothervalue`.

Comment: @JonH what you expect is what I expected; looking for `IS NOT 'closed'` does *not* return where is `NULL`, I think you misread my question

Comment: `NULL` means “there is no real value for this field.” And as such, you can not check for it with comparison operators such as `=` or `!=`, because those _do_ check values.

Comment: `WHERE status IS NOT 'closed'` would return a syntax error, not a resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most operations (except `IS NULL`) in SQL return `NULL` when they get `NULL`. You can treat this like "undefined" and the result of any operation where input is undefined delivers an undefined result. This can become very confusing for instance in cases like this: `CONCAT('a', NULL, 'b')` results in `NULL`, too.

This is not MySQL-specific. Wikipedia has a long discussion of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but that's not the way that `NULL` works.  `NULL` is defined not to return true in any comparison except `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  Even `NULL = NULL` returns `FALSE`.  You can use the `COALESCE` function to make your code easier to read and write, like

```
WHERE COALESCE(status,'') <> 'closed'
```

This strangeness is in fact part of the SQL standard, not a MySQL issue.  It's one of the reasons you don't want to use NULL values in columns like status.

Comment: `NULL = NULL` returning `FALSE`, aiiii. I definitely now understand why I should avoid using `NULL` as a value to be compared.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing anything to `NULL` results in `NULL` (excluding when using the null operators).  The clause `IS NOT 'closed'` when it hits a null field in arecord is basically doing:

```
  NULL != 'closed'
```

As stated above, even though you think this is a true statement,  this will result in a `NULL` being returnd, which is treated as a false in the where condition so the record with not match and be part of the result set.

You must use the explicit `is null` and `is not null` operators.

Answer (score 0):

Nulls is not ordinary values, in the reference manual is is stated like this:

> The NULL value can be surprising until you get used to it. Conceptually, NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated somewhat differently from other values.
>
> To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

You can not check for equality, inequality, grater than, less than, etc.

Comment: "You can not check for equality, inequality, grater than, less than, etc."
But you can; `IS NOT NULL` and `IS NULL` both behave as expected and are equality comparisons.

Comment: Yes you MUST use them (IS (NOT) NULL) (or in your case include thees statements in your where clause) if you want your results to include the records that have nulls in the field you are testing, otherwise they are ignored. They are NOT the same operator as the equality operator for testing defined values e.g. '=' and '!='.